# How to set up launch images to support iOS 6 through iOS 9?

Tags: ios, splash-screen, ios9, default.png

I am currently developing a game for both iPhone and iPad that only supports landscape orientation. However, all my launch screen art is in portrait mode in all sizes required to support all apple devices.

It worked fine until new iOS 9 when every device I tested on started using default.png(art used as launch screen for iPhone 4-sized screen) resulting in game being shrunk on screen.

I also tried using image assets to define launch screen for each screen size class(all for portrait orientation) supporting iOS 7 and greater. It removed the issue of shrunken screen on iOS 9 but it also made iOS 7 and 8 devices display default black screen on launch.

Since I'm running out of ideas can somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: If your app is only for landscape, why are you all of your launch images in portrait? Provide landscape launch images instead of portrait ones.

Comment: If launch image orientation is important, then why did it work like this until iOS 9? Also I did try and create landscape oriented images and it didn't help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running into this myself.  It appears that to support iOS7, you need the launch images. To support iOS8, you could either use launch images, or a 'LaunchScreen.xib" defined in your project settings. (Defined in 'App Icons and Launch Images).

Now in iOS9, it is REQUIRED that you use the .xib file.  So to support iOS7 thru iOS9, you need to have BOTH that images, as well as a defined launch screen file.

What sucks is that for those of us who never had a launch screen file defined, our apps will look like crap on iOS9 until an update is released.

(if anyone has a better solution, please post it!).

Comment: No better solution by now, this is (sadly) perfect